# how to find recently ejected device?

Tags: windows-10, removable

My windows 10 Alienware keeps throwing random (USB?) "device ejected" sound when there isn't. Is there a log somewhere I can check to see what was being ejected? Hope my comp is not infected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information may be recorded in Windows 10 event logs, but this log is not enabled by default. You need enable this event log first.

Please open Event Viewer first. Then located to **Applications and Service Logs**->**Microsoft**->**Windows**->**DriverFrameworks-UserMode**->**Operational**->Right click **Operational** and select **Properties**->Select **Enable logging**. Now you can track USB flash drive usage with Windows 10's Event Viewer.

Also, here is an article talking about [How to track down USB devices in Windows 10 with Microsoft's USB Device Viewer](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/tracking-down-usb-devices-in-windows-10-with-microsofts-usb-device-viewer/), you could check if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Nirsoft's free [USBDeview](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) summarizes USB device information, including time connected and disconnected.

That said, I've found some hubs and external cameras to be a bit flaky. Perhaps there are loose connections inside, perhaps the device is very sensitive to electrostatic pickup (which seems to be the problem for one mini-camera I've used), so double check that all USB devices are physically stable and not near mains cords. Double-stick tape to the desk helped a hub stay connected, for example.